# Why isn't my app finding the jquery module :Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory?

Tags: jquery, node.js, angular, npm, bootstrap-4

I am transferring an Angular project in which a bootstrap template has been implemented to my project. (I don't know if this is a good idea)
One of the things that I did is, add these to the angular.json file:

```
 "styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "../assets/sass/paper-dashboard.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
          "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
          "../node_modules/arrive/src/arrive.js",
          "../node_modules/moment/moment.js",
          "../node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.js",
          "../node_modules/bootstrap-notify/bootstrap-notify.js"
        ],
```

I have obviously run this command:

> npm install

But, I keep getting this error:

I tried changing ../ with / in the paths, this way:

```
  "styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "/assets/sass/paper-dashboard.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
          "/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
          "/node_modules/arrive/src/arrive.js",
          "/node_modules/moment/moment.js",
          "/node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.js",
          "/node_modules/bootstrap-notify/bootstrap-notify.js"
        ],
```

However, this still didn't resolve, my problem.

Here's the project structure:
[image]

Any thoughts on this?
Thank you.

Comment: `npm install` installs the pacakges in package.json not files on angular.json. I would also make sure that those files exist in the path you specified, just in case you copied that from somewhere else and the paths don't match, expand the node_modules and check that the files are actually in those folders

Comment: @rmjoia yes those files do exist in the node.module. I do know that npm install installs the packages.json. One of those packages contains the jquery.js file. However, my app doesn't seem to be able to find it. I am wondering whether the fact that the node_modules folder isn't highlighted has something to do with it.

Comment: actually is "faded" I think that's because it's just ignored by VSCode does your solution contains sensitive data? else push it to a github repo so people can clone and see what is going on.. at least for me is hard to make sense of what it can be with printscreens, I would have to try to recreate the whole solution and who knows it could even work locally.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will consider that

Answer (score 0):

in your file  package.json 
there are red lines[image]

in gitbash console inside the project folder do so

```
npm install jquery popper.js
npm install boostarp
```

Comment: No, I don't have red lines